# Mdx, greater than works like String and not Numeric (Saiku)

Tags: mdx, saiku

I am using Saiku and trying to filter by mdx, using the symbol '> (greater than)', in the default Sales cube. The problem is that's it filtering like String and not Numeric. The values that I want for the query below is **[51,52]**, but the server olap response is **[6,7,8,9,51,52]**. Any idea how can I filter that?

Here's the query:

```
WITH
SET [~ROWS] AS
{
    FILTER([Time].[Weekly].[Week].Members, [Time].[Weekly]. [Week].CurrentMember.Properties("Caption") > '50')
}
SELECT
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Unit Sales]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [Sales]
```

Answer (score 0):

The response is to use 'Cint', like bellow:

```
WITH
SET [~ROWS] AS
    {
    FILTER([Time].[Weekly].[Week].Members, Cint([Time].[Weekly].[Week].CurrentMember.Properties("Caption")) > 50)
    }
SELECT
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Unit Sales]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [Sales]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be alternative approaches. With experimenting as some may be more efficient.

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.ValueColumn as [Date].[Calendar].[July 1, 2001].MemberValue  
MEMBER Measures.KeyColumn as [Date].[Calendar].[July 1, 2001].Member_Key  
MEMBER Measures.NameColumn as [Date].[Calendar].[July 1, 2001].Member_Name  

SELECT {Measures.ValueColumn, Measures.KeyColumn, Measures.NameColumn}  ON 0  
from [Adventure Works]
```